# Changing anchor text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Example HTML:

```
<div id="video-quality" style="">
<a class="low bttn" href="">
<span>Low Quality</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Hey im trying to use JavaScript to target an anchor tag and change it's current text of "Low Quality" to "High Quality".

I don't really know JavaScript very well, but this is what I have come up with. But it's obviously not working:

```
var vid_id=document.getElementById('video-quality');
var anchor=vid_id.getElementsByTagName('a');
anchor.innerHTML="High Quality";
```

Comment: The result of `.getElementsByTagName()` is an array. You should access it's elements and not the array itself.

Comment: @MarkoDumic: It's not an array. It's a `NodeList`.

Comment: `@T.J. Crowder` said that the `@MarkoDumic` was a **Array** for clarity for novice users how to work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Of course, but I just wanted to point out rather then be precise, otherwise I'd need to explain what a NodeList is (the OP is obviously not proficient with JS).

Comment: @MarkoDumic: Fair 'nuff, it's just that there are substantial differences between them (not least that `NodeList` instances are *live*). Perhaps "...is an array-like thing called a `NodeList`" with a link to the spec.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the `video-quality` `div` will only ever have **one** anchor in it, you're not far off:

```
var vid_id=document.getElementById('video-quality');
var anchor=vid_id.getElementsByTagName('a');
anchor[0].innerHTML="High Quality";
//    ^^^-- change here
```

*(There's a shorter way if you don't need to support IE7 and earlier, see [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280239/157247) for more.)*

The key was in the name `getElementsByTagName` (note the plural). It returns a [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), not an element. A `NodeList` is (shockingly!) a list of matching nodes, in this case matching *elements*. `innerHTML` is a property of individual elements, so we have to index into the `NodeList` to access a specific element. The code above assumes there is at least one matching element, and updates its HTML. If you want to be more defensive:

```
var vid_id=document.getElementById('video-quality');
var anchors=vid_id.getElementsByTagName('a');
if (anchors[0]) {
    anchors[0].innerHTML="High Quality";
}
```

That allows for the possibility there are no matching anchors.

Note that by doing this, you're removing the `span` element, since the `span` is a descendant of the anchor. If you wanted to avoid that, just look for `span` elements as descendants of the anchor, exactly as you've looked for anchors in the `div`.

---

FWIW, I'd recommend using a reasonable JavaScript browser-focussed library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They provide a *lot* of utility functionality, and smooth over some browser differences. But if you prefer using the DOM directly, that's fine too.

Comment: Note that this will also remove the SPAN element around the text node.

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t need legacy support (IE7-), you can write:

```
document.querySelector('#video-quality a span').innerHTML = 'High Quality';
```

If you DO need legacy support, I recommend a library like jQuery or similar to make selecting DOM nodes much simpler from a singe, wide-spread API.

Answer (score 4):

Plain javascript:

```
var vid_id = document.getElementById('video-quality');
var span = vid_id.getElementsByTagName('span');
span[0].innerText='High Quality'
```

Or you can just use jQuery:

```
$('#video-quality span').text('High Quality');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: A) The OP hasn't mentioned jQuery. B) Your "plain JavaScript" example doesn't work for the same reason the OP's code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Simple is best.
Just give the span element an id and then alter it directly.

```
<div id="video-quality" style="">
<a class="low bttn" href="">
<span id="quality-setting">Low Quality</span>
</a>
</div>
```

then script is:

```
document.getElementById('quality-setting').innerHTML="High Quality";
```